# Validity of Newton's second law in a non-inertial reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, inertial-frames, free-body-diagram

Suppose two observers are mutually interact through gravitational force (assuming they are alone at space). If the reference frame is fixed in one of the observers could the observer in the reference frame argue that second law of Newton doesn't hold because he doesn't accelerate with respect to reference frame? Does he need to introduce a pseudo-Force so ΣF=ma is valid?

Comment: *If the reference frame is fixed in one of the observers could the observer in the reference frame argue that second law of Newton doesn't hold because he doesn't accelerate with respect to reference frame?* Could you please reword this. I think some words are wrong or missing.

Comment: **Does he need to introduce a pseudo-Force so ΣF=ma is valid?** - Yes that is exactly why pseudo-forces are used..

Comment: Yes, he does. I don't see why this is a question for you given that you know about the non-inertial frames and pseudo forces.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.